# Bootstrap Dialog: Animate size changes

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a simple bootstrap dialog for a login form asking for email and password. I have a link at the bottom to for the user to create an account that displays the additional fields required for signup. The additional fields are displayed and the dialog is resized in order to display them. How do I animate the changing size of the dialog?

https://jsfiddle.net/w2nj33kb/

Dialog HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signin-dialog">Sign in</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="signin-dialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign in</h4>
      </div>
      <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="signup-fields">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" name="password2"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Email options:</div>
                <div class="email-options">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1" checked="checked"/>
                    Newsletter</label>

                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="news-alerts" value="1"/>
                    News Alerts</label>

                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="modal-footer-options col-sm-8">
            <span class="modal-footer-signup">Not a member? <a href="#">Sign up</a> to track stocks and receive alerts.</span>
            <span class="modal-footer-signin">Already a member? <a href="#">Sign in</a> to access your stocks.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer-buttons col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ( function($) {

        $('.modal-footer-signup a').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#signin-dialog').addClass('signup');

            $('.signup-fields').fadeIn(1000);
            $('.modal-footer-signup').fadeOut(500, function() {
                 $('.modal-footer-signin').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
        $('.modal-footer-signin a').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#signin-dialog').removeClass('signup');

            $('.signup-fields').fadeOut(500);
            $('.modal-footer-signin').fadeOut(500, function() {
                 $('.modal-footer-signup').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    } )(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: can you create fiddler for this?

Comment: edited to include the fiddle

Comment: I still think slideDown is what you are after: https://jsfiddle.net/m35uv6fq/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "animate" but you could just replace your .fadeIn and .fadeOut with .slideUp and .slideDown. Apologies if this is not what you meant by "animate".

```
$('.modal-footer-signup a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#signin-dialog').addClass('signup');

        $('.signup-fields').slideDown(500);
        $('.modal-footer-signup').fadeOut(500, function() {
             $('.modal-footer-signin').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
    $('.modal-footer-signin a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#signin-dialog').removeClass('signup');

        $('.signup-fields').slideUp(500);
        $('.modal-footer-signin').fadeOut(500, function() {
             $('.modal-footer-signup').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
```